# Splitting contents of column to other columns based on non-numeric identifier

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, split

I have a large data frame with many columns. There is one column with some numeric values and some non-numeric strings. I want to split up the non-numeric strings and place the contents in other existing columns. However, when I run the for loop, I get the following error:
`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'`

Original:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Status':['Active','Active','Inactive','Active'], 'Source':['Domestic','International','International','Restricted'], 'Activity':['In Progress','Post','Post','In Progress'], 'FY20':[2,55,52,99],'FY21':[90,20,11,43],'FY22':[10,52,57,9]})

df['Status'] = pd.Categorical(df['Status'],categories= ['Inactive','Active'])
df = df.sort_values('Status')
df['Source'] = pd.Categorical(df['Source'],categories= ['International','Restricted','Domestic'])
df = df.sort_values('Source')

df.loc['Active - In Progress Subtotal'] = df.loc[(df['Status'].isin(['Active'])) & (df['Activity'].isin(['In Progress']))].sum(axis=0)
df['index1'] = df.index
print(df)


##this part is producing the error

for i in range(len(df)):
  if not pd.isna(df.loc[i, 'index1']) and not df.loc[i, 'index1'].isnumeric():
    split_string = df.loc[i, 'index1'].split('-')
    df.loc[i, 'Status'] = split_string[0]
    df.loc[i, 'Source'] = split_string[1]
```

Original output:
[image]

Desired Output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Status':['Active','Active','Inactive','Active','Active'], 'Source':['Domestic','International','International','Restricted','In Progress Subtotal'], 'Activity':['In Progress','Post','Post','In Progress',""], 'FY20':[2,55,52,99,101],'FY21':[90,20,11,43,133],'FY22':[10,52,57,9,19]})

df['Status'] = pd.Categorical(df['Status'],categories= ['Inactive','Active'])
df = df.sort_values('Status')
df['Source'] = pd.Categorical(df['Source'],categories= ['International','Restricted','Domestic','In Progress Subtotal'])
df = df.sort_values('Source')
```

[image]

Comment: The posted code throws a different error `TypeError: 'Categorical' with dtype category does not support reduction 'sum'` , `in <module>
    df.loc['Active - In Progress Subtotal'] = df.loc[(df['Status'].isin(['Active'])) & (df['Activity'].isin(['In Progress']))].sum(axis=0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you would use a loop is unclear, but to fix your code a few things are needed:

- don't keep Categoricals or you won't be able to assign new values
- convert your values to string in the test
- pass the indices, not the positions to `loc`

```
df = df.sort_values('Status', key=lambda s: pd.Categorical(s, categories= ['Inactive','Active']))

df = df.sort_values('Source', key=lambda s: pd.Categorical(s, categories= ['International','Restricted','Domestic']))

df.loc['Active - In Progress Subtotal'] = df.loc[(df['Status'].isin(['Active'])) & (df['Activity'].isin(['In Progress']))].select_dtypes('number').sum(axis=0)
df['index1'] = df.index

for idx in df.index:
  if not pd.isna(df.loc[idx, 'index1']) and not str(df.loc[idx, 'index1']).isnumeric():
    split_string = df.loc[idx, 'index1'].split('-')
    df.loc[idx, 'Status'] = split_string[0]
    df.loc[idx, 'Source'] = split_string[1]
```

A vectorial variant:

```
m = ~df['index1'].astype(str).str.isnumeric()
df.loc[m, ['Status', 'Source']] = df.loc[m, 'index1'].str.split(' *- *', expand=True).values
```

Output:

```
                                 Status                 Source     Activity   FY20   FY21  FY22                         index1
2                              Inactive          International         Post   52.0   11.0  57.0                              2
1                                Active          International         Post   55.0   20.0  52.0                              1
3                                Active             Restricted  In Progress   99.0   43.0   9.0                              3
0                                Active               Domestic  In Progress    2.0   90.0  10.0                              0
Active - In Progress Subtotal    Active   In Progress Subtotal          NaN  101.0  133.0  19.0  Active - In Progress Subtotal
```